# How do we justify certain steps in the solution to gambler's ruin?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

The problem of gambler's ruin asks the following: suppose a player begins with $k$ units of money, $0<k<N$. Each turn he flips a coin and either gains a unit of money with probability $p$ or loses a unit of money with probability $1-p$. The game ends when he reaches $N$ and wins or $0$ in which case he loses the game. What is the probability of losing?

The usual solution, which you can find for example on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin or in Grimmett & Stirzaker - Probability and Random processes, page 17, proceeds by constructing a linear difference equation using the fact (using the notation from wikipedia) that $P(R_n|H)=P(R_{n+1})$ where $R_n$ is the event "that the player is ruined having started with $n$ units of money" and $H$ is the event "of winning the first flip".

> What event exactly is $R_n$? Is it correct to consider $H$ to be a single event or should we take a separate event for every coin flip?

The approach taken by Grimmett and Stirzaker seems conceptually the same, but instead of using a single probability measure, they use $P_k$ - the probabilities calculated relative to the starting point $k$. Then they use the equation $P_k(A) = P_k(A|B)P(B) + P_k(A|B^C)P(B^C)$, where A is the event of losing the game and B is the event of winning the first flip. I am not completely sure what they mean by $P$, my best guess is that because the probability of $B$ is independent of $k$, they just drop the index. Next they use the fact that $P_k(A|B) = P_{k+1}(A)$ which looks essentially as expressing the same relation as the equation with $R_n$ before.

Anyway, I haven't been able to completely justify this relation theoretically, so here comes my main question:

> How exactly do we justify $P(R_n|H)=P(R_{n+1})$ and $P_k(A|B) = P_{k+1}(A)$?

I have tried translating this problem to a more familiar measure-theoretical language, using $\Omega = \lbrace-1,1\rbrace^\mathbb{N}$ as the underlying sample space and defining $M:\lbrace-1,1\rbrace^\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{N}\cup\lbrace\infty\rbrace,$ $M(f,k) = \min\lbrace m\in\mathbb{N}|\sum_{i=1}^m f(i) = k \rbrace$ (where $\min\emptyset := \infty$), which then enables us to define $R_n = \lbrace f\in\Omega|M(f,-n) < M(f,N-n)\rbrace$ and $H = \lbrace f\in\Omega|f(1) = 1\rbrace,$ but this hasn't given me any new intuition and may not even be the correct formalization.

It seems increasingly likely that I am missing some implicit assumption in the statement of the problem that is obvious to probabilists but not so much to me ... In this case:

> What exactly is this assumption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David gives the probabilistic perspective, which is the most useful way of thinking about problems like this once you're confident that you could reason about them formally. Terence Tao's excellent [review of probability theory](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/254a-notes-0-a-review-of-probability-theory/) discusses the "probabilistic way of thinking" (and contains much other goodness besides).

Your formalisation works (you just need to define a measure for it to be complete).

> How exactly do we justify $P(R_n|H)=P(R_{n+1})$ and $P_k(A|B)=P_{k+1}(A)$?

If we were to go line by line, it would look like this:

$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[R_n|H] &= \mathbb{P}[\lbrace f\in\Omega|M(f,-n) < M(f,N-n)\}|f(1)=1]\\
                  &= \mathbb{P}[\lbrace f\in\Omega|\min\{m\in\mathbb{N}|\sum_{i=2}^m f(i)=-n-1\} < \min\{m\in\mathbb{N}|\sum_{i=2}^m f(i)=N-n-1\}| f(1)=1]\\
                 
                  &= \mathbb{P}[\lbrace f\in\Omega|\min\{m\in\mathbb{N}|\sum_{i=2}^m f(i)=-n-1\} < \min\{m\in\mathbb{N}|\sum_{i=2}^m f(i)=N-n-1\}]\\
 \end{align}$

, since $f(1)=1$ and $\lbrace f\in\Omega|\min\{m\in\mathbb{N}|\sum_{i=2}^m f(i)=-n-1\} < \min\{m\in\mathbb{N}|\sum_{i=2}^m f(i)=N-n-1\}$ are independent events.

$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[R_n|H]&= \mathbb{P}[M((f(2),f(3),\cdots),-n-1)<M((f(2),f(3),\cdots),N-n-1)]\\

&= \mathbb{P}[M((f(1),f(2),\cdots),-(n+1)) < M((f(1),f(2),\cdots),N-(n+1))]\\
&=\mathbb{P}[R_{n+1}]
\end{align}
$

The penultimate line follows because the sequences $(f(1),f(2),\cdots)$ and $(f(2),f(3),\cdots)$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I was hoping for. I am still a bit confused about the steps from line 4 to line 5 and from line 5 to line 6. Why can we drop the condition $f(1) = 1$? Probably because $f(1)$ does not appear in the sums, but is it possible to see this from the definition of conditional probability? And the step from line 5 to line 6 seems like some kind of isomorphism, but I can't see what exactly it is. Maybe it's really obvious but I've been studying probability all day and my brains don't work properly at the moment.

Comment: @DejanGovc Hopefully I've clarified the answer.

Comment: I think that mostly does it. I still have some minor issues to solve, but I think I'll ask that as a separate question if it turns out to be a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

$R_n$ is simply the event that the gambler starts with $n$ units of money, plays the game, and loses (that is loses all his money).  $H$ is indeed the event that the gambler wins on the first flip, thus increasing his fortune by 1 (and allowing him to continue playing).

This is the reason why $P(R_n|H)=P(R_{n+1})$.  Given the event $H$, the gambler increases his fortune by 1; and at this point, it's as if he had just started playing the game with a fortune of $n+1$ units of money. So, the probability that he loses the game starting with $n$ units of money, given that he wins the first flip,  is exactly the same as the probability that he loses the game starting with $n+1$ units of money.

I'm not quite sure what $P_k$ represents (what do you mean by "relative to the starting point"?), but I suspect similar reasoning will establish its formula.

Comment: This is a nice intuitive explanation. By "starting point" they mean the amount of money you have when you start playing. I'm not quite sure about the details though ...